# postgres syntax error on grant select on table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
            CREATE TABLE abc AS
            SELECT title            
            FROM people
            WHERE title like 'ram%'           
            GRANT SELECT ON abc IN SCHEMA public TO ram;
```

But on running this: I get the following syntax error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "IN"
LINE 26:         GRANT SELECT ON abc IN SCHEMA publi...
```

without grant query its working fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the schema, use `ON public.abc`.
The syntax `IN SCHEMA public` can only be used with `ON ALL TABLES`.

Also, you have to separate `CREATE TABLE` and `GRANT` with a semicolon, as they are two separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not support `GRANT` syntax during `CREATE TABLE` command.  You'll need to separate them.

For the `GRANT`, you will be better off prefixing the table name with schema (i.e., `public.abc`), as `IN SCHEMA` syntax is not supported unless you're `GRANT`ing `ON ALL TABLES`.  Here's a full working example:

```
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
            CREATE TABLE abc AS
            SELECT title            
            FROM people
            WHERE title like 'ram%';
            GRANT SELECT ON public.abc TO ram;
```